# Unable to position BitmapImage on InkCanvas

Tags: c#, wpf, path, bitmapimage, inkcanvas

I have read all that I can find and can't solve this. My goal is to capture strokes from the `InkCanvas` and convert these into a `Path`. From the path, return a `BitmapImage` to an `Image` control and place the `Image` control at an arbitrary position on the `InkCanvas`.

If I write on the `InkCanvas` a "< >", I get the following result:

1. Only the left "<" of the strokes is shown as a bitmap. (don't see
   the ">").
2. The area outside of the "<" is BLACK -- not transparent.
3. I can't figure a simple way of reducing the Path to just the drawn
   strokes. i.e., I can't see how to clip the space above and to the
   left of the drawn "<>".

From the window, this is my code to manipulate the `Image`:

```
    void MakeFigure_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ShapeMaker shapemaker = new ShapeMaker();
        System.Windows.Shapes.Path myshape = shapemaker.StrokesToPath(InkCanvas.Strokes);
        InkCanvas.Strokes.Clear();

        Image image = new Image();
        ImageSource img = shapemaker.PathToBitmapImage(myshape);
        image.Source = img;
        image.Width = img.Width;
        image.Height = img.Height;
        InkCanvas.Children.Add(image);
        InkCanvas.SetLeft(image, 800);
        InkCanvas.SetTop(image, 400);
    }

    public Path StrokesToPath(StrokeCollection strokeCollection)
    {
        Path path = new Path();
        PathGeometry pathGeo = new PathGeometry();

        foreach (Stroke stroke in strokeCollection)
        {
            StylusPointCollection strokepoints = stroke.StylusPoints;

            PathFigure pathFig = new PathFigure();
            pathFig.StartPoint = new Point(strokepoints[0].X, strokepoints[0].Y);

            for (int i = 1; i < strokepoints.Count; i++)
            {
                pathFig.Segments.Add( new LineSegment()
                {
                     Point = new Point(strokepoints[i].X, strokepoints[i].Y)
                });
            }

            pathGeo.Figures.Add(pathFig);
        }

        path.Data = pathGeo;
        path.Stroke = Brushes.White;       
        path.StrokeThickness = 4;           

       return path;
    }

    public BitmapImage PathToBitmapImage(Path path)
    {
       var bounds = path.Data.GetRenderBounds(null);
       path.Measure(bounds.Size);
       path.Arrange(bounds);

        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
          (int)bounds.Width *4 , (int)bounds.Height*4 , 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        rtb.Render(path);

        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

        using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(stream);
            stream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bi.StreamSource = stream;
            bi.EndInit();
            bi.Freeze();
        }

        return bi;
    }
```

Comment: I think I found the problem. For some reason, Canvas.SetLeft and Canvas.SetTop do not work on my InkCanvas because my inkcanvas is defined as a custom ink canvas... CustomInkCanvas inheriting from InkCanvas. How do I set the image for CustomInkCanvas?

Comment: Suggestons edited back to the problems at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Canvas.SetLeft(image, 800);
Canvas.SetTop(image, 400);
```

with

```
InkCanvas.SetLeft(image, 800);
InkCanvas.SetTop(image, 400);
```

*InkCanvas doesn't inherit from Canvas* and exposed it's own attached properties. So, you need to call InkCanvas methods and not Canvas methods.